# API / Plugin Architecture Development Ideas

Tags: c#, vb.net, plugins

I'm trying to figure out a way to develop a plugin-based architecture software. The basic structure would be that my main application ('MainApp') will start, search through the plugin DLL files in a specified folder, and load them one by one using Activator. The DLL files are supposed to be created by my team and I plan on laying out a documentation for other users to develop the plugins as well.

Right now I have a sample project up and running. I use an interface class ('PluginInterface') through which I cast type and load plugins. I can communicate with the plugins through specified functions, properties and subroutines.

My question is that the interface method defines which properties, functions, subs or events can be found inside a plugin class. What I want to do is that I have many components or controls available in my MainApp. I need to allow my plugin to access those components. For example, I have a notification control ('NotifyCtrl') that would allow plugins to show popup notifications on the screen. That control has properties and methods of its own. So I have a big arsenal of controls that I want to allow plugin to access.

I cannot understand how to develop such architecture that runtime-loaded plugins are able to access controls/components of MainApp. I mean I can access components of plugin using PluginInterface, but how does the plugin know which components/properties/functions are available for use by MainApp. How should I write code inside one of my plugins (for example 'ChatPlugin')…. MainApp.NotifyCtrl.ShowNotification("hello")?

Thanks

Comment: Whiteboard questions are often better suited for [programmers.se].  And, what you're looking for, is to pass an instance of some type to your plugins that abstracts away the various actions you wish them to control.  They call methods on the instance, you act accordingly.

Comment: Are you planning for the future or do you think you know what the host will need to do for the plugins?

Comment: My MainApp will be hosting many plugins and should be able to access the controls inside MainApp, which include a notification center, network communicator, etc. Its up to the plugin's capability what to create using those controls. But I can't figure out how to allow plugin to access those controls in a direct manner (e.g. Notifier.ShowMessage; instead of Dim n as New Notifier, n.ShowMessage).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in such a case is create a base library off of which your application runs. This means that you need to create an abstract class or interface for every class you want the plugin developers to see.

For example, in your main app let's say you have a "User" class which you want to have shared events and variables:

```
    //Create an instance of user in your application where you allow setting and getting the Name.
    public class User : IUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public event Action OnLogin = delegate { };
    }


    //Only allow the developers to get the name/id
    public interface IUser
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string Id { get; }

        event Action OnLogin;
    }
```

Then, for example if you want the developer to access all the logged in users in your application, you have some kind of main connecting point, such as a static class where you manage everything.

```
    //Your functionality goes here
    public class UserManager : IUserManager
    {
        private Dictionary<int, User> Users = new Dictionary<int, User>();

        public override User this[int id]
        {
            get { return Users[id];}

        }

        public override IEnumerator<IUser> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Users.Values.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(User user)
        {
            Users[user.Id] = user;
        }
    }

    //What the user can see goes here
    public abstract class IUserManager : IEnumerable<IUser>
    {

        public abstract User this[int id] { get; }

        public abstract IEnumerator<IUser> GetEnumerator();

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

To tie it all up, and give them full access to access the enumerable:

```
public class MyApp : MyPluginApp
    {
        public static UserManager MyUserManager { get { return Manager as UserManager; } }
        public static void Start()
        {
            //Start routine
            Manager = new UserManager();


            MyUserManager.Add(new User {Id = 0, Name = "test"});
        }
    }
    public class MyPluginApp
    {
        public static IUserManager Manager { get; protected set; }

    }
```

Then, your plugin developer can do as something as easy as:

```
var userOfInterest = MyPluginApp.Manager.First(x => x.Name == "test"); //Get user by the name of test
```

They can easily access Id / name, but they cant set it, nor can they add new users, etc. This also makes it easier for you because you do not need to create extra functions for every function you want to export, instead you just create a function in the base class, and implement it in your application.

Comment: You gave a detailed response but I'm really sorry I couldn't figure out how to implement it. I understand the part that I need to move the definitions that can be used by plugins into a base class library. So Now I have 3 objects; a MainApp which is the main program and loads plugins, has a control called NotificationControl. Then a BaseClass object that defines the interface for plugin, and a plugin DLL that implements interface obtained from BaseClass. How does my plugin access the NotificationControl's methods. (would appreciate if you share links to example code, if any)

Comment: Could you take a look at my sample project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20856352/API%20Platform.zip

Comment: I'll take a look and also setup a sample project / library example as well once I get home from work later today

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution to what I'm looking for. Using the Reflection method of loading plugins are runtime is usually a one-way interaction method... host application using the capabilities of plugin class. What I'm looking for is the both ways, host using plugin's resources and the plugin using host's controls/resources, etc.

So the Reflection method is outdated. The 3.5 and above .NET frameworks provide System.AddIn feature, this is made for such type of architectures.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163476.aspx

Comment: Turns out this is not the best option. MAF requires a complex directory structure to be present in the host application directory, which I don't want. And a hideous 7 project solution.